# php-cgi keeps shutting down on windows

Tags: vbscript, php

I am running Windows 8 with Nginx as a web server, and php as my language. I created a vbs script to easily start `php-cgi`, and it looks like this:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("C:\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000"), 0, True
```

The script works, php works, but the issue I am having is that from time to time php will stop or shut down. I am not sure if this has to do with the script or the php settings. Why does `php-cgi` keep stopping from time to time? I don't like having to restart it constantly.

Linux boxes don't seem to have this issue, as I have run php for months without it shutting down.

Comment: Try checking for bugs https://bugs.php.net

Comment: Does it also exit when you run it alone at the command prompt?  Is there a way to capture the output from the PHP process?  Have you tried using a batch script instead [as suggested in this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4539670/168868)?

Comment: So I followed that some, and changed some php settings for my database stuff, I guess we'll have to wait and see what happens.

Comment: If anyone else wondering its because you have to add the system PATH variable "php_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" to 0